# Не работающие кнопки-ссылки z-index

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Эффект тени мешать кнопкам-ссылкам работать, как можно не пожертвовав эффектом исправить это?

```
.effect
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect:before, .effect:after
{
  z-index: -3;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
  opacity: 0.35;
}
.effect:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете ввиду, что псевдоэлементы перекрывают ссылки, то добавьте свойство

> pointer-events: none;

Элементы с данным свойством не реагируют ни на какие события, как-будто их нет, хотя визуально ничего не измениться.